# Escaping Markdown for use with the C preprocessor

Tags: markdown, c-preprocessor

I would like to combine Markdown and C-preprocessor directives in the same file. The problem is that `#` has a meaning in both languages. Assuming that the C-preprocessor runs first, how can I espace any `#` used in e.g. Markdown headings?

Comment: In addition to Mark Leighton Fisher's answer, you might consider the `m4` macro processor as a more flexible alternative to the cpp.  It doesn't need `#`, and it's likely that any system with cpp installed will also have `m4`.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a C preprocessor macro with the value "#". An example:

```
#define HASHMARK #

Some text before.

HASHMARK 47 != 42
HASHMARK 48 != 42
HASHMARK 49 != 42

Some text after.
```

Example output (as preprocessed with gcc 4.5.3 on Cygwin):

```
Some text before.

 # 47 != 42
 # 48 != 42
 # 49 != 42

Some text after.
```

You may need to tweak this so the spacing is correct for your application.